# How to launch an application with different Gtk+ 2 theme?

Tags: firefox, gtk2, qt4, audacity, wxwidgets

I'm trying to use a dark Gtk+ theme, and everything goes fine with native Gtk+ apps, and well, only with Gtk+ apps. I mean, wxWidgets and Mozilla's apps looks terrible, if not counting unreadability (see screenshot below). Rendering Gtk's buttons and fonts in Qt apps looks bad too.

[image: Audacity, Icedove and Iceweasel using Gtk+ 2 dark theme]

I've learned Mozilla's apps could improve readability (text on light background become readable **but** text on dark background becomes hard to read) by adding this to `gtk-2.0/gtkrc`:

```
style "moz" {
text[NORMAL] = "#000000"
base[NORMAL] = "#FFFFFF"
}
class "GtkInvisible" style "moz"
apwidget "GtkInvisible" style "moz"
```

So I came out with this solution: start these apps with a 'fallback' light Gtk+ 2 theme (let's say Adwaita). But launching with something like `GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` could change gtk's PNGs (like buttons and checkboxes), **not** the color scheme:

[image: Audacity launched with Adwaita theme]

I noted that doing this, it returns some warnings, e.g.:

```
$ GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc audacity

(Audacity:12322): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
$ GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc icedove

(process:13204): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

With Qt(4) apps, I tried to use a native good-looking theme like Breeze, but couldn't find a way to choose it after installing (I had no luck using `qtconfig-qt4`).

Here are some of my software versions (I'm using Debian testing):

- Gtk+ 2: 2.24.28
- Gtk+ 3: 3.16.6
- Qt4: 4.8.7
- wxWidgets: 3.0.2 (Audacity's version is 2.0.6)
- Iceweasel (Firefox): 38.1.0
- Icedove (Thunderbird): 31.7.0

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I would be really glad to see any answer, even if it's specific to only one application.